# Test cases discovery using django-jenkins

Tags: django, unit-testing, jenkins, django-jenkins

I am using django framework for my project and now I in order to move to continous integration I am planning to use jenkins. natually django-jenkins is the choice.

I am using django unit test framework for unit testing and using patterns finding for testcases discovery.

```
./manage.py test --patterns="*_test.py"
```

I have installed and configured django-jenkins and all other necessary modules. Now when I am running the jenking for running the unit test cases, jenkins is not able to discover the test cases.

[image]

```
./manage.py jenkins
```

Is there some syntax to be followed while naming the unit test files or unit test cases itself?

I also could not find any pattern searching parameter to be used with jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

All options from standard django test runner should works (https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins/pull/207) but i'd newer tested them all.

Comment: Feel free to create an issue on github it that case )

Comment: thanks for your reply..Currently I am bit bsy with my stuff I will do it next week, for sure!